# How to dynamically append sections to Symfony 2 configuration?

Tags: symfony

```yml
my_bundle:
    algorithm: blowfish # One of 'md5', 'blowfish', 'sha256', 'sha512'
```

This configuration is done by this configuration tree:

```php
// Algorithms and constants to check
$algorithms = array(
    'md5'      => 'CRYPT_MD5',
    'blowfish' => 'CRYPT_BLOWFISH',
    'sha256'   => 'CRYPT_SHA256',
    'sha512'   => 'CRYPT_SHA512',
);

$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->scalarNode('algorithm')
            ->isRequired()
            ->beforeNormalization()
                ->ifString()
                ->then(function($v) { return strtolower($v); })
            ->end()
            ->validate()
                ->ifNotInArray(array_keys($algorithms))
                ->thenInvalid('invalid algorithm.')
            ->end()
            ->validate()
                ->ifTrue(function($v) use($algorithms) {
                    return 1 != @constant($algorithms[$v]);
                })
                ->thenInvalid('algorithm %s is not supported by this system.')
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

Since each algorithm requires different parameters, how can I dynamically add them as children of the root node, base on the selected algorithm?

For example, if algorithm is "blowfish" there should be a scalar node named "cost", while if "sha512" a scalar node "rounds", each with different validation rules.

**EDIT**: what I really need is figure out the current algorithm (how to do with `$rootNode`?) and than call on of:

```
$rootNode->append($this->getBlowfishParamsNode());
$rootNode->append($this->getSha256ParamsNode());
$rootNode->append($this->getSha512ParamsNode());
```

**EDIT**: possible configurations I'd like to accomplish:

```
my_bundle:
    algorithm: blowfish
    cost: 15
```

Another:

```
my_bundle:
    algorithm: sha512
    rounds: 50000
```

And another:

```
my_bundle:
    algorithm: md5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check (using `ifTrue()`) if the value of `algorithm` is `md5`. If this is the case, you unset the `blowfish`, `sha256`, `sha513` keys in the array containing the raw config values.

You can then use a similar logic if `algorithm` is `blowfish`, `sha256` or `sha513`.

---

```php
$rootNode->
    ->beforeNormalization()
        //...
        ->ifTrue(function($v) {
            // $v contains the raw configuration values
            return 'md5' === $v['algorithm'];
        })
        ->then(function($v) {
            unset($v['blowfish']);
            unset($v['sha256']);
            unset($v['sha512']);
            return $v;
        })
        ->end()
        // ...do same logic for the others
    ->end();
```

You'd have to use something like this:

```yml
my_bundle:
    algorithm: blowfish
    md5: #your params
    blowfish: #will be unset if algorithm is md5 for example
    sha256: #will be unset if algorithm is md5 for example
    sha512: #will be unset if algorithm is md5 for example
```

As you mention, you can then append all of them:

```php
$rootNode->append($this->getMd5ParamsNode());
$rootNode->append($this->getBlowfishParamsNode());
$rootNode->append($this->getSha256ParamsNode());
$rootNode->append($this->getSha512ParamsNode());
```

### EDIT

There is also a `thenUnset()` function.

### EDIT

Doctrine's [way of doing it](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php) might be of interest here.

Comment: Doesn't seem an elegant solution to me, but I'll think about it. Thanks for helping!

Comment: There is a great example with Doctrine [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php) where they have a similar case with addOrmSection() and addDbalSection().

Answer (score 0):

Gremo, maybe im on the wrong track here. BTW, thanks for your reply on my question.

Its just an opinion maybe its just a silly answer... well here we go.

For your answer i know that you already know/understand how a [bundle extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) works.

Maybe you can define the 4 empty params needed as seen on [configuring-services-and-setting-parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#configuring-services-and-setting-parameters)

...*you'll set this parameter in your extension class, based on the incoming configuration values*...

Then you can have specific checks on the tree (like if algorithm is 'blowfish' then cost is required)

```
$rootNode->
    ->beforeNormalization()
        ->ifTrue(function($v) {
            // $v contains the raw configuration values
            // if 'algorithm' blowfish -> cost isRequired
            // or as you said on your question you can call
            // ->append($this->addBlowfishParametersNode())
        })
        ->then(function($v) {
            // maybe some unsetting, but not needed
        })
        ->end()
    ->children()
        // ...
    ->end()
;
```

Check "[Appending Sections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#appending-sections)"

```
public function addBlowfishParametersNode()
{
    $builder = new TreeBuilder();
    $node = $builder->root('parameters');

    $node
        ->isRequired()
        ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but the problem is that inside the callback (`ifTrue`) the `$v` argument is just a plain array (current node value). That is I can't call `append()`, as it's defined only for [`ArrayNodeDefinition`](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Builder/ArrayNodeDefinition.html).