# Symfony 2: How to dynamically adjust configuration parameters

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, configuration

For my `AppBundle` (THE APPLICATION ITSELF, NOT A REUSABLE BUNDLE) I have a configuration parameter that is a path.
I'd like to be sure the path ends with a `/`.

In this moment I have a method in the entity that uses this path (yes is an entity and not a controller) adjust the configuration parameter with a code like this:

```
public function buildLogoFolder($folder)
{
    // Replace the placeholder with the current Entity's URL
    $folder = str_replace('{entity_domain}', $this->getDomain()->getCanonical(), $folder);

    $folder = rtrim(ltrim($folder, '/'), '/') . '/';

    return $folder;
}
```

As the `$folder` parameter comes from the `config.yml` file I'd like to move outside of the entity this adjustment.

I think I should use a solution similar to the one suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651871/how-to-dynamically-append-sections-to-symfony-2-configuration), that is the use of the `DependencyInjection` component.

I think the process is very similar to the [loading of](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) a [configuration file](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html) for a new bundle as explained in the Symfony's documentation but I'm not sure on how to proceed.

Is there someone who can put me on the right way?

**I'd like to automate the process. I want read the `folder` configuration parameter value and then adjust it with the method I wrote above.**

**I want to be sure that the `folder` parameter configured ever ends with a trailing slash, also if the developer didn't write it in the configuration.**

**So, If the developer write something like `path/to/folder` the resulting configuration parameter is automatically adjusted to `path/to/folder/`**.

Comment: You want to override the config file if the developer write the path folder without `/`?

Comment: Not all the config file, but only the value of the `folder` parameter (question updated to be more precise)

Comment: How do you actually load that config option right now? Is it just a container parameter? Do you have a container extension?

Comment: No, I havent' a container extension. Currently I don't load by myself config parameters, as they are loaded by Symfony. The parameter I want to check and edit is set in the `app/config.yml` file, where all the default `AppBundle` configuration parameters reside. Is the default application bundle.

Comment: You could use a compiler pass to clean it up: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html.  But honestly, just doc the correct format and go with it.  Trying to anticipate and correct these sorts of error seems to be an exercise in futility.

Comment: @Aerendir Is this any good for you? [Setting dynamic values to keys in config.yml](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/bvet/setting-dynamic-values-to-keys-in-config-yml)

Comment: Agreed with @Cerad as this seems overly complex.  What's wrong with keeping it in your Entity function?  That seems like the far better place for it.  You said this isn't a reusable bundle, which means you should have some measure of control over the source code anyway - just use code reviews, document the format, and call it a day.

Comment: @JasonRoman, the same check is performed also in other entities, so I have the same code reproduced in other parts of the application. I'm looking for a way to abstract it. I do unit tests, but the problem is that the code is duplicated, and I don't like this. Also, the entity isn't the best place to put this kind of code, as it is wrote to handle paths and not information that regard to an entity. Is some sort of a "marginal code". I don't know if I'm understandable. Anyway, I don't want duplicated methods. This is the real point.

Comment: @Cerad, yes, it is also for exercise, but I'm sure that doing this I'll learn a lot about how configurations work in Symfony, preparing me to write, in future, reusable bundles. In this moment I haven't the time to learn how to, but learning this small part of a reusable bundle appeal me... Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it because it seems to me the best correct approach.

Comment: What about creating a utility class where that duplicated code was in a static function call that you could invoke from anywhere, or in a service, or a trait that your classes implement?

Comment: @JasonRoman, yes, may be a simpler solution!

Comment: You should take a look at the Config component and how to check and load config files and implement a config tree builder. see http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#validation-rules. Logic could then go in `->validate()` method of your node